# Incompatilble types in my FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I get an error when I try to return a new fragment. I suspect it has something to do with the imports but I must be wrong using just Android's fragmentpageradapter does not change anything, I'm out of ideas and just want it to work so I can see it in the emulator running.

My FragmentPagerAdapter class:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;


/**
 * Created by HP_user on 01/12/2015.
 */
public class SampleFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    final int PAGE_COUNT = 3;
private String tabTitles[] = new String[] { "Home", "Shouts", "Shouters" };


public SampleFragmentPagerAdapter(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public int getCount() { return PAGE_COUNT; }



@Override
public android.Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return Home.newInstance(position + 1);
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    // Generate title based on item position
    return tabTitles[position];
   }
}
```

My main activity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Get the ViewPager and set it's PagerAdapter so that it can display items
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new SampleFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

        // Give the PagerSlidingTabStrip the ViewPager
        PagerSlidingTabStrip tabsStrip = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        // Attach the view pager to the tab strip
        tabsStrip.setViewPager(viewPager);
    }

}
```

Main activity fragment class:

```
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

    public MainActivityFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page, container, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to add the error!

Comment: i did add the error its in the first class displayed,

Comment: @Override
public android.Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return Home.newInstance(position + 1);
}

Comment: @g24l i added it in the comments, forgive me i'm new here

Comment: i imported support library v13, its fixed my previous error but now my fragment manager is giving me an error, asking for v4 support? any clues @g24l

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the `android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter` class can only be used with support Fragments, i.e. `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`.

You have two choices to fix it.

**Choice 1)**  Make all of your Fragments `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` instances instead of `android.app.Fragment` instances.

**Choice 2)**  Use the `android.support.v13.app.FragmentPagerAdapter` class from the v13 support library, which makes it possible to use regular Fragments, [see documentation here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v13/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html).

Comment: thank you i have added it but now my fragment manager is producing an error, its in the brackets of my super after my fragment manager,